# Fourier transform of $\mathrm{e}^{ik|x|}$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of $\mathrm{e}^{ik|x|}$? Here, $k > 0$ is real.

I use the definition $$ F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega x} f(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$

Thanks!

Comment: Although your definition makes no sense, you can try taking the integral from $-n$ to $n$ and taking limits as $n$ goes to infinity in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that definition in order to compute that Fourier transform, because that formula is valid for elements in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and the function $x\mapsto e^{ik|x|}$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I know that the solution will be some distribution on the Schwarz space, but I think its more clear to state the problem without distributions.

Comment: It's not more clear when your definition is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\mathcal F[H] = -\frac i w + \pi \delta(w), \\
\mathcal F[e^{i k x} H(x) + e^{-i k x} H(-x)] = \\
\delta(w - k) * \mathcal F[H] + \delta(w + k) * \mathcal F[H](-w) = \\
-\frac i {w-k} + \pi \delta(w-k) + \frac i {w+k} + \pi \delta(w+k) = \\
-\frac {2 i k} {w^2 - k^2} + 2 \pi k \delta(w^2-k^2),$$
where $1/(w-w_0)$ and $1/(w^2-w_0^2)$ are p.v. functionals.

Comment: Nice! Its not totally clear to me how the $2\pi k$ factor appears in front of the delta function, but thanks :)

Comment: It's the formula for the change of variables, saying that if $f$ has only simple zeroes, then
$$\delta(f(w)) = \sum_{w_i: f(w_i) = 0} \frac {\delta(w - w_i)} {|f'(w_i)|}, \\
\delta(w^2-k^2) = \frac {\delta(w-k)} {2k} + \frac {\delta(w+k)} {2k}.$$